# button animation error: Cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined (line 11)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, error-handling, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a custom button animation for my Wix website it is written in JavaScript and I get this error when I plug the code into an `onclick` event:

> *"cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined"*

I've tried removing the return and I think the problem has to do with some sort of `iframe` issue because the original code was built to run in an html `<iframe>` element but that dident end up working out.

If someone could rewrite this code so that it dosent give this error that would be super helpful.

```
export function button7_click(event) {
  $w.window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return $w.window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      $w.window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      $w.window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      $w.window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      $w.window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        $w.window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
  })();

  Math.randMinMax = function(min, max, round) {
    var val = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));

    if (round) val = Math.round(val);

    return val;
  };
  Math.TO_RAD = Math.PI / 180;
  Math.getAngle = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var dx = x1 - x2,
      dy = y1 - y2;

    return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  };
  Math.getDistance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var xs = x2 - x1,
      ys = y2 - y1;

    xs *= xs;
    ys *= ys;

    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys);
  };

  var FX = {};

  (function() {

    var canvas = $w.document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      lastUpdate = new Date(),
      mouseUpdate = new Date(),
      lastMouse = [],
      width, height;

    FX.particles = [];

    setFullscreen();
    $w.document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', buttonEffect);

    function buttonEffect() {

      var button = $w.document.getElementById('button'),
        height = button.offsetHeight,
        left = button.offsetLeft,
        top = button.offsetTop,
        width = button.offsetWidth,
        x, y, degree;

      for (var i = 0; i < 40; i = i + 1) {

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {

          y = Math.randMinMax(top, top + height);

          if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            x = left;
            degree = Math.randMinMax(-45, 45);
          } else {
            x = left + width;
            degree = Math.randMinMax(135, 225);
          }

        } else {

          x = Math.randMinMax(left, left + width);

          if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            y = top;
            degree = Math.randMinMax(45, 135);
          } else {
            y = top + height;
            degree = Math.randMinMax(-135, -45);
          }

        }
        createParticle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          degree: degree,
          speed: Math.randMinMax(100, 150),
          vs: Math.randMinMax(-4, -1)
        });
      }
    }
    $w.window.setTimeout(buttonEffect, 100);

    loop();

    $w.window.addEventListener('resize', setFullscreen);

    function createParticle(args) {

      var options = {
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2,
        color: 'hsla(' + Math.randMinMax(160, 290) + ', 100%, 50%, ' + (Math.random().toFixed(2)) + ')',
        degree: Math.randMinMax(0, 360),
        speed: Math.randMinMax(300, 350),
        vd: Math.randMinMax(-90, 90),
        vs: Math.randMinMax(-8, -5)
      };

      for ($w.key in args) {
        options[$w.key] = args[$w.key];
      }

      FX.particles.push(options);
    }

    function loop() {

      var thisUpdate = new Date(),
        delta = (lastUpdate - thisUpdate) / 1000,
        amount = FX.particles.length,
        size = 2,
        i = 0,
        p;

      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(15,15,15,0.25)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

      ctx.globalCompositeStyle = 'lighter';

      for (; i < amount; i = i + 1) {

        p = FX.particles[i];

        p.degree += (p.vd * delta);
        p.speed += (p.vs); // * delta);
        if (p.speed < 0) continue;

        p.x += Math.cos(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);
        p.y += Math.sin(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.rotate(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD);

        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.fillRect(-size, -size, size * 2, size * 2);

        ctx.restore();
      }

      lastUpdate = thisUpdate;

      $w.requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }

    function setFullscreen() {
      width = canvas.width = $w.window.innerWidth;
      height = canvas.height = $w.window.innerHeight;
    };
  })();
}
```

The button once clicked should run the JavaScript code and play the animation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is `$w`?

Comment: for some reason wix and corvid say that its undefined without that $w sign before the function.